# Most efficient way for doing multiple PCAP filters

Tags: linux, pcap

I have an application that using `libpcap` as the mechanism for acquiring packets, and I need to filter out different protocols for different parts of the application. I need to consider optimization as the streams will have a high rate of traffic (100-400 Mbps).

What I would really like to be able to do is set up a live capture (no filter), and then selectively filter packets after the capture is made. It doesn't seem like this is possible (the bpf is built into the capture mechanism from what I can tell).

If this indeed is not possible, there are two  other ways of doing it (that I have thought of), and I am not sure what would be considered more efficient or 'better':

1. Make multiple captures each with their own filter
2. Make one capture (no filter) that dumps to fifos, and have other captures read from those fifo (with their own filters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fifo-approach is probably not very efficient as it involves copying lots and lots of memory from A to B (e.g. 400mbps buffered - they must not block each other - to four fifos, each having a different filter, deciding to throw away 99.99% of accumulated 1600mbps).  Multiple captures on the other hand only trigger action in userland if there is actually stuff to do. The filtering is (usually) done in the kernel.

A third approach is to use libwireshark, the lower portion of Wireshark, to do filtering (and wtap for capturing). This involves quite some code overhead as libwireshark is not exactly in perfect shape for third party use outside of Wireshark.
However this does come with the ability to use Wireshark's "Display Filters", which are compiled to bytecode and reasonably efficient. Many filters may be compiled once and may look at the same frame one after another. You may be able to "stack" filters as e.g. "*ip.tcp*" implies "*ip*".
This becomes quite efficient if you are able to generate the most common element of all filters and place it as a BPF-filter on your capturing device. The display-filters then only look at data that might interest at least one of them.